# How to delete all my browser cookies using PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, logout

I have 2 instances of an applications that are running on the same domain and they are located

1. Main folder `/`
2. A sub folder `/staging/`

I am testing some code on the `"/staging"` instance.
When a user logs out I want to completely clear all her/his cookies.

The log in and the log out are handled in the same file `index.php.`

To log out, the user have to click on a link that takes her/him to `index.php?action=logout`

The issue that I am having here is that when the user logs out **not** all the cookies are removed. The cookie named `phone_call_timer` will not be deleted unless I refresh the log out (ie, `index.php?action=logout`) page again (2 times) which makes no since to me but this is what I am facing! I don't know if there is an issue with my code or a bug somewhere in `PHP 5.5.12`

So the first time I go to `index.php?action=logout` to logg out, but 1 cookie will still be saved (ie . `phone_call_timer`)

However, when I refresh (F5) the page "execute the log out code again" the cookie disappears.

Why the `phone_call_timer` cookie is not removed from the first time? 
How can I fix this issue?

**Note:** if I navigate to `index.php` or any other url the cookie will never disappear.

Here is a screen shoot after the first log out (as you can see the `phone_call_timer` cookie is still there but it should have been removed at this time.
[image]

Here is a screenshot after I refresh the log out page again (as you can see the `phone_call_timer` cookie is now gone!)
[image]

here is my PHP code the content of `index.php` file

```
<?php

    require 'requires/APP_configuration.php';
    require 'requires/PHP_generic_functions.php';

    require 'classes/Connection.php';
    require 'classes/Session_Manager.php';

    //define this page name
    define('pageTitle' , SYSTEM_NAME . " - Sign In");
    define('pageDescription', "Sign In");
    define('pageKeywords', "Sign In");

    define('ADD_GLOBAL_META_TAGS', '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/captcha/jquery.captcha.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="js/captcha/captcha.css" rel="stylesheet">
        ');



    $session = new \classes\Session_Manager(SESSION_NAME, SESSION_MAX_AVAILABLE, SESSION_SAVE_PATH, SESSION_SAVE_URL, SESSION_HTTPS_ONLY);
    $ref = "none";
    $newURL = 'index_bridge.php';
    $redirectTo = '';
    $newURLAfterRefresh = 'index.php';
    $action = '';
    $loggedOut = 0;

    if(      isset($_GET['ref']) 
        && ! empty($_GET['ref']) ){
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    }



    if( isset($_GET['redirectTo']) && !empty($_GET['redirectTo']) ){
        $redirectTo = $_GET['redirectTo'];
        $newURL = $redirectTo;
    }
    if(!empty($redirectTo)){
        $newURLAfterRefresh = 'index.php?ref=' . $ref . '&redirectTo=' . $redirectTo;
    }

    $newURLshort = $newURL;
    if(strpos($newURL, '?') !== false){
        $newURLshort = substr($newURL, 0, strpos($newURL, '?') );
    }

    $file_found = file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $newURLshort);

    if(!$file_found){   
        $newURL = 'index_bridge.php';
    }



    /********** START CODE **********/
    //BEGIN current page's code

    if(isset($_GET['action'])){
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    }

    if(empty($action)){
        $session->resumeSession();

        if( $session->isAutherized() === true ){
            header('Location: index_bridge.php');
            exit();
        }   
    }

    if($action == 'logout' ){

        $cookies = array();
        $var = str_replace('/','', SESSION_SAVE_PATH);
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
            $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        }

        $session->destroy();    
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {

            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);

            if($name == 'phone_call_timer' && $ref == 'auto'){
                continue;
            }

            setcookie($name, null, time()-MAX_STORE_COOKIE);
            setcookie($name, null, time()-MAX_STORE_COOKIE, '/');
            setcookie($name, null, time()-MAX_STORE_COOKIE, $var);
            setcookie($name, null, time()-MAX_STORE_COOKIE, SESSION_SAVE_PATH);

            unset($_COOKIE[$name]); 
        }

        $loggedOut = 1; 
    }


/**********************************************************
********************* START OUTPUT ************************
**********************************************************/
    //This should always be the first output
    include 'includes/meta.php';
    ?>
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#user_field,#password_field').keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
            $('#sign_in').click();

    });

    $('#sign_in').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Please wait...');

        if ($(this).prop("disabled"))
            return false;

        $(this).prop("disabled", true);

            $('#respond').removeClass('bg-danger').text('');
            $.ajax({    
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/handler-sign-in.php',        
                data: $('#signinForm').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function(data) { 

                    if(!data)
                        return;


                    if(data.success == true)                    
                        window.location.href = '<?php echo $newURL ?>';                 
                    else {
                        $('#respond').addClass('bg-danger').text(data.msg);
                        $('#sign_in').prop("disabled", false);
                        $('#sign_in').html('Sign In');

                        if(data.human_check_required == 1)
                            $("#humachCheck").show();
                        else 
                            $("#humachCheck").hide();

                    }

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#responseAddForm').removeClass().addClass('errorBox').html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown + '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus + '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');         
                }
            });
    });

    $("#humachCheck").captcha({
        captchaDir: "js/captcha",
        formId: "signinForm",
        url: "ajax/set-correct-captcha.php"
    });

});
</script>

<?php




    //Display the activity table
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<div class="Body">';

        if($loggedOut){
            echo '<div class="passBox"><p style="text-align: center;">You have successfully logged out<br><a href="'.$newURLAfterRefresh.'">Click Here</a> to login.</p></div>';

        } else {

            //login form
            echo '  <div style="width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="account-wall">
                            <img class="profile-system-logo" src="images/accordiLogoX200.png" alt="Logo">
                            <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to continue to '.SYSTEM_NAME.'</h1>
                            <div id="respond" class="margin-lg-around center-block padding-md-around"></div>
                            <form class="form-signin" id="signinForm" method="post">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="user_field" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus="autofocus">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_field" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <div id="humachCheck" class="box-hidden" style="margin: 10px 0;">You must enable javaScript in order to use this system</div>
                            <div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="sign_in">Sign in</div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>';


        }


    //close Body DIV
    echo '</div>';





include 'includes/menu_master_bottom.php';
include 'includes/footer.php';



/**********************************************************
********************* END OUTPUT ************************
**********************************************************/

/********** END CODE **********/


?>
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with this:  if($name == 'phone_call_timer' && $ref == 'auto'){
                continue;
            }     It appears to be skipping that particular cookie under certain conditions - make sure that condition isn't interfering at the wrong time.

Comment: I run into the same issue even if I remove that line completely

Comment: Ok. Then I guess that's not it.  ;-) Worth a shot.

Comment: I have the same problem tried this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484, but it is not working for me now im looking in a way to remove it using javascript which i think is better

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki thanks for your input. If you are looking for a solution using jQuery try this https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie I have been using it and it works great

Comment: @Mike thanks bro i will look into it cuz im going crazy, facebook sdk and google creates cookies and it is too much i can't re-write the same jquery code for each cookie if there is a solution to remove all cookies without specifying its name